# I want to pass a json array elements to an html page

Tags: java, json

I have a json array in DAOImpl.I am giving the code here.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= allTickets.size()-1; i++) {
    obj.put("ticketId", allTickets.get(i).getTicketId());
    obj.put("category", allTickets.get(i).getCategory());
    obj.put("task", allTickets.get(i).getTask());
    obj.put("subject", allTickets.get(i).getSubject());
    obj.put("query", allTickets.get(i).getQuery());
    obj.put("priority", allTickets.get(i).getPriority());
    obj.put("date", allTickets.get(i).getDate());
    obj.put("modifiedDate", allTickets.get(i).getModifiedDate());
    System.out.println(obj);
    jsonArray.put(obj);
}
```

How can i pass this array to an html page and iterate the array and get the result in a web server.

Comment: It is very unclear what your problem is and what you've tried to solve it hitherto. Please edit your question to make it more clear, show us what you've tried, and give details about the problem (expected result, current result, error messages, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use java script (Ajax get function) to get the Json object from the server. In the ajax success function you can then process the results of the GET request.

This way you can iterate the array and display the array items in HTML elements or you can print out HTML content on the page.